# routing ppp <-> wireguard interfaces

Tags: vpn, routing, wireguard, fortigate, point-to-point-protocol

I want to connect via wireguard to a droplet that will be running openfortivpn for connecting to a 192.168.11.0/24 network. I have confirmed that only traffic to 192.168.11.* goes through fortivpn and everything else comes out of my droplet ip.

I have the following wg-quick configuration on the server:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = <snip>
Address = 10.8.1.1/24
ListenPort = 54321

[Peer]
PublicKey = <snip>
AllowedIPs = 10.8.1.2/32
```

I don't know if I have to actually change something in there or could otherwise help me for bringing it on already routed e.g. PostUp.

on bringup, it does the following

```
[#] ip link add fortiwg type wireguard
[#] wg setconf fortiwg /dev/fd/63
[#] ip -4 address add 10.8.1.1/24 dev fortiwg
[#] ip link set mtu 1420 up dev fortiwg
```

classic wireguard

now, openfortivpn on bringup creates a ppp0 interface like this

```
ppp0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1354
        inet 192.168.222.113  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 192.0.3.1
        ppp  txqueuelen 3  (Point-to-Point Protocol)
        RX packets 111  bytes 1101 (1.0 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 111  bytes 1107 (1.0 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

and wireguard's like this:

```
neon: flags=209<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP>  mtu 1420
        inet 10.8.1.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  destination 10.8.1.1
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 1000  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I want to know, what is it I have to do to route the wireguard traffic to ppp0 (both ways) on traffic to/from 192.168.11.0/24?

Comment: This is really usual routing, nothing special. Is your 192.168.11.0/24 behind ppp0? Which address has the 192.0.3.1 towards this network? Host 192.0.3.1 must have a route to 10.8.1.0/24 via 192.168.222.113 and whatever is behind that host must have a route to 10.8.1.0/24 via it; hosts behind neon must have a route to 192.168.222.113, 192.0.3.1 and 192.168.11.0/24 via 10.8.1.1. Draw a network diagram, it will be easier to answer with concrete commands. Also, *please* forget `ifconfig` and `route` commands already and always use `ip addr` and `ip route` from `iproute2`.